# Separate HDD or separate partition  for Solr Indexing

Tags: solr

What is best when using solr... using a separate HDD or SSD for hosting solr index data? Or just a separate partition on HDD?

Just concern about Search & Indexing performance on solr on Windows Server R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the index data in the same partition as other services has no benefits as Solr will still compete with other processes for access to the same spindle.

It is standard procedure for all search engines to place the index in a separate spindle from other data.

SSDs are a viable option for storing index data even though they are not widely used for critical data. SSDs are much faster than HDDs but not as reliable. This is not a concern with indexes though, as you can "easilly" rebuild the index if the SSD crashes.

Comment: What about using a separate HDD?

Comment: That's what I meant when I wrote that using a separate spindle is SOP. I didn't write "HDD" because only small installations use a single separate disk. Most will use disk arrays which means you have to make sure the index doesn't end up on the same disk/spindle as other data.